# Powershell script to check folder for files and send email

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a script to work but I'm running into some issues.  We have a folder that gets ZIP files sent to it via FTP and a service on the server moves them to another directory for processing.  The issue is sometimes the service will be running but not doing anything so the monitoring doesn't sent a alert.  I am working on a PowerShell script to check the folder for .zip files older than 30 minutes and if found send a email to that team to check out why the files haven't been moved.  Below is what I have written so far, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
$Path = "c:\test"
$SMTPServer = "mail.server.com"
$From = "Monitor Prod <mon.server.com>"
$To = "people@server.com"
$Subject = "Alert: Potential issue with service in PROD"


$SMTPMessage = @{
To = $To
From = $From
Subject = "$Subject"
Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}

$File = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter ".txt" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}
If ($File)
{   $SMTPBody = "Batches older than 30 minutes located in c:\test while service is actively running. Service may require a restart."
$File | ForEach { $SMTPBody += "$($_.FullName)`n" }
Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem with your code? I think you need to update `-Filter "*.txt"` at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did the *.txt and simplified it a little bit and its working.